# Can javascript style "alert('test');" be done on linux desktop using terminal?

Tags: javascript, linux, terminal, centos

in javascript if you run...

```
alert('test');
```

a new window pops up and displays

```
test
```

in linux desktop, all you can do is run

```
echo test
```

but all this does is echo it in the terminal

it does not open a new pop up window like java does.

Comment: This may help http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-produce-pop-up-message-box-alert-window-from-shell-script-149866/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use notify-send command. You need to have libnotify installed.

Example `notify-send test`

Another you could try is xmessage.

Example `xmessage test`

Comment: libnotify ( `yum install libnotify -y` )worked great, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`gxmessage` command should work.

Another command, `gdialog`

Answer (score 0):

`alert` is not a standard javascript api method, it is introduced by web browsers. In this issue, to display a popup window in linux desktop environment, you can use notify-send or gnome-osd-client or something like that, from a command line.

So if you want to show a notification from javascript, make sure your javascript runtime(node.js, rhino, or something like that) supports system command line execution(Try [child_process.spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) in node.js or [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) in java